# Facebook AS3 API - getSession() always returns NULL, login() does not create pop-up?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, facebook, facebook-graph-api

EDIT: Fixed most of the problem (but not too sure why). Check the bottom of the post for my note.

I am doing my first AS3 Facebook project from scratch, so apologies for any stupid mistakes.

Anyhow, I created a simple class that init()'s the Facebook class object and prompts you to login if there is no getSession() currently in place. Now the problem is I can never get anything but NULL out of getSession() and calling Facebook.login() doesn't do anything at all.

You'll see in the code that Facebook.login() is conditional based on whether or not one can getSession(), but I have tried this without that check as well and I don't even get the callback fired.

Any ideas?

I followed a tutorial on http://www.permadi.com/blog/2011/02/using-facebook-graph-api-in-flash-as3-1-5/ just in case there's something blatantly wrong in my code (it's his fault).

Code below:

```
    public function init():void {           
        Facebook.init(_appID, checkLoginStatus, null, _accessToken, true);
    }

    // facebook methods -----------------------------------------------------  /

    private function checkLoginStatus(response:Object, error:Object):void {

        if (Facebook.getSession() && Facebook.getSession().accessToken){ configLoginData(); }
        else if(!error) { promptLogin(); }
    }

    private function promptLogin():void {
        $requireLogin.dispatch();
    }

    // login / logout -------------------------------------------------------  /

    public function login(e:* = null):void {

        Debug.log("Facebook PROMPT LOGIN " + Facebook.getSession(), Debug.GREEN);

        if(Facebook.getSession() && !Facebook.getSession().accessToken){
            Facebook.login(checkLoginStatus, {perms:"publish_stream"});
        } else {
            Facebook.logout(logoutComplete);
        }
    }
```

I also have it running off of my server which is properly hooked up to an App (as required). You can see it here: http://themoleking.com/laboratory/facebook_as3/FacebookAPI.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I figured it out by digging through the Facebook API code.

If you enter oauth=true when you are calling Facebook.init(), it will automatically make all session calls NULL.

I don't know enough about the API yet to know why that is, but at least I'm making some progress :)

Answer (score 0):

you have to take care of the javascript part for all to work.

in the head section of your html page, include these javascript files

```
<script type=”text/javascript” src=”http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js”></script>

<script type=”text/javascript” src=”http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js”></script>
```

next, you need to include a div with id="fb-root" in the body of same page.
then the popup will show up for your user to login.

if you want to get the init handler function to fire,
you must embed you flash movie with this code

```
    <script type=”text/javascript”>
swfobject.embedSWF(“yourfile.swf”, “flashContent”, “1000″, “700″, “9.0″, null, null, null, {name: “flashContent”});

</script>
```

your flash object id must match it's name for cross browser sake

then make sure you do all the Facebook.init() and login() in the main timeline of your as3
or your document class.
doing them elsewhere other than root will give you nightmares.
hope this help